# Spyder3 crash on ubuntu

Tags: python, python3, spyder

I install Spyder3 but when I try to run it, it crash.
error log is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 2331, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 2215, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 734, in setup
    message=_("Spyder Internal Console\n\n"
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/plugins/console.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.find_widget.set_editor(self.shell)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/findreplace.py", line 260, in set_editor
    from spyderlib.qt.QtWebKit import QWebView
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/qt/QtWebKit.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  # analysis:ignore
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtWebKit'
```

I see some similar question here but the log error was different and the suggestion find do not help to solve the problem.

Comment: You are not alone in this mess... there is hundreds of programs using Qt4 and got like this after debian (and throught it it creeped to ubuntu) decided to pack Qt4 libs without QtWebKit. well QtWebKit is deprecated but its removal from Qt4 is some kind of bad joke...

Comment: Please read [my answer on other thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/972194/66509).