# Can't open spyder3 in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, python

I was trying to use spyder 3 in ubuntu. I installed spyder3 using `pip3 install spyder`. But it doesn't open. When I open in terminal it gives me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/spyder3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 144, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 49, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 40, in check_qt
    package_name, required_ver = qt_infos[qtpy.API]
KeyError: 'pyside'
```

Comment: See [my solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/972194/66509) on the duplicate question.