# Spyder not running

Tags: software-installation, spyder

I have ubuntu 16.04.3, pip3, python 3.5.  I ran the command "sudo pip3 install spyder" on terminal and spyder got installed, I can see the icon in installed programs but when I click it nothing happens.  In Terminal if I run "spyder3", I get following

```
vikram@vikram-K52F:~$ spyder3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ImportError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/spyder3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 144, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 49, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 39, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
vikram@vikram-K52F:~$
```

Comment: I have the text of the terminal when spyder was installed, but it is very big to be included in the question

Comment: See complete solution howto install spyder3 3.2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/972194/66509).